Initial lag in video streaming of locally stored video using FastAPI
I have stored some videos on aws ec2 instance and want to stream them using FastAPI backend. But the videos stream with an initial lag of 1 to 2 seconds then it plays smoothly. Below is my streaming endpoint:
@router.get("/stream_video/")
async def stream_video(
    video_path, 
    mode: int
):
    if not os.path.exists(video_path) or not os.path.isfile(video_path):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Video file not found")
    
    if mode == 0:
        async def video_streamer(file_path):
            async with aiofiles.open(file_path, mode='rb') as file:
                while chunk := await file.read(5 * 1024 * 1024):
                    yield chunk

        file_size = os.path.getsize(video_path)
        file_name = os.path.basename(video_path)
        # Encode the filename for Content-Disposition
        encoded_file_name = urllib.parse.quote(file_name)
        headers = {
            "Content-Disposition": f'inline; filename=*=UTF-8\'\'{encoded_file_name}',
            "Content-Length": str(file_size),
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
        }

        return StreamingResponse(video_streamer(video_path), headers=headers)
    elif mode == 1:
        return FileResponse(
            path=video_path,
            media_type="video/mp4",
            filename=os.path.basename(video_path)
        )

I tried with smaller chunk size (1MB) then tested it with gradually increasing the size but nothing helped. On further research I found out i need to move the 'moov' atom in the video file to the start of video, so i did that using:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -movflags faststart -c copy output.mp4

Now I am stuck here and cannot understand what I should do to remove the initial lag. P.S, the videos are not of very high data and bit rate.

I have tested your code (which I guess you might have taken from this answer), using a video provided in this answer, and there doesn't seem to be any issue. Note that streaming a file that is saved on disk, as in the first linked answer, you would notice minimal delay (maybe less than a second), but streaming a file that is being downloaded from another source on the web first, as in the second linked answer, the delay might be much more noticable.

Hence, if you are downloading the video from AWS in the backend before streaming it to the client, it is very normal to experience a couple of seconds delay. The delay might also be due to the browser performing some buffering on the response, before displaying the data.

@AmmarAhmed How are you watching the videos that you stream? It's possible the problem is with the file encoding/reading process or problem is with the streaming process itself. Also "I am streaming" usually means "I am sending out" but your code seems to be receiving video data from an existing file path. What is the video's resolution and duration (maybe 5 mb is too small for holding the metadata)? Is there a testable video_path from online?
